# Erro de Caracteres especiais Json

Tags: jquery, json

Tenho um script onde, depois de selecionado o primeiro select ele me retorna no segundo select a moeda referente ao país, porem esses paises e moedas quando se tem carecteres especiais está me trazendo "B�snia e Herzegovina"

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var paises = null;
var moedas = null;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "../paises.json",
    contentType: "application/json ; charset=UTF-8",
    cache: false,
    success: function(retorno) {
            paises = retorno;
            $.each(paises,function(i, pais){
                $('#pais').append($('<option>', {
                                    value: paises[i].sigla_moeda,
                                    text: paises[i].pais
                                }));
            });
    } 
});
$('#pais').change(function(){
    $("#moeda").empty();
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "../moedas.json",
    contentType: "application/json ; charset=UTF-8",
    cache: false,
    success: function(retorno) {
            var moedas = retorno;
            $.each(moedas,function(i, moeda){
                if($('#pais').val() === moedas[i].sigla){
                    $('#moeda').append($('<option>', {
                                value: moedas[i].sigla_moeda,
                                text: moedas[i].moeda
                            }));
                }
            });
    } 
});
})
```

desde já, agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua página deve estar usando UTF-8 e teu JSON deve ter sido salvo como iso-8859-1/ANSI, faça o seguinte, abra ambos json `paises.json` no sublimetext ou notepad++ e salve-os como UTF-8:

- Para salvar usando SublimeText:

  [image: salvando documento em ANSI com notepad++]
- Para salvar usando notepad++:

  [image: salvando documento em iso-8859-1 ou windows 1252]

Ainda sim note que talvez seria melhor se os acentos fossem escapados com `\u`, ou seja, quem gerou os arquivos deveria ter feito isso para evitar perdas nos acentos, como por exemplo:

```
{ "cidade": "S\u00e3o Paulo" }
```

Então o JavaScript mesmo interpretaria isto e nem precisaria você escapar nada.

Só pra constar, content-type **em requisições** HTTP não mudam a codificação das **resposta HTTP**:

```
contentType: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Ou seja, isso só afeta se você enviar JSON via payload com POST, não vai afetar em nada a resposta recebida após o envio.

Comment: Cara você me salvou, muito obrigado. Segui seus esclarecimento e retirei o contentType. Valeu!

Comment: @ericoliveira por favor, poderia marcar a resposta como correta? Fica ao lado esquerdo da resposta, se não souber como fazer leia as instruções em: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635